# pick random word from builtin Android word dictionary

Tags: android, random, dictionary, cpu-word

As Android suggests words while typing this suggests that all the dictionary words are available in the system. I want to pick a random word from this existing word list.

I have Googled it and searched it on stackoverflow as well. I have also seen the sample code available at android-sdk\samples\android-14\SearchableDictionary\src\com\example\android\searchabledict which tells how to create a `ContentProvider` and access it to search word.

One more solution to it is create a text file with words and access it but then the size of app becomes larger.

If I could access the existing list then the size will be smaller.

It will be of great help if you can redirect me to some tutorials for this or a code

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: And what about you place file on SD card? or just convert .txt to .bin a then perform converting and reading into some structure.

Comment: but if I could access the available list all these processing can be avoided